# How to add a style.css to React/Laravel app?

Tags: html, css, laravel

I'm building a React/Laravel app. However, when I tried to style the layout, I found that I cannot edit in `public/css/app.css` since every time I run the `npm run dev` command, the changes I've made disappear from the `app.css`.

Therefore, I created a `style.css` but I was confused about whether I should put the `style.css` into the `public` folder or `resources` folder. Moreover, after looking at Laravel docs, this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#plain-css) said that I should add a code to `webpack.mix.js`. So here's what I wrote

```
.styles('public/css/style.css', 'public/css/all.css');
```

adding this to the last part of the whole code:

```
mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .styles('public/css/style.css', 'public/css/all.css');
```

After running `npm run dev`, I refreshed the page and the page is still not showing the changes from `style.css`.

Here is my repo: https://github.com/kikidesignnet/hotelreviews and my website which I'm editing: http://immense-beach-76879.herokuapp.com/

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you should tag reactjs to this. My answer below is for laravel only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `all.css` file to your main layout.

Comment: and make sure to put the `styles.css` in your resources directory

Comment: Thanks. I also add <link href="/css/all.com" /> to the blade.php too.